# Reframe wordpress sidebar to put alternate widgets side-by-side

Tags: css, responsive-design, multiple-columns, sidebar

I am adapting a Wordpress site to make the theme responsive. This includes an alternate display mode for the sidebar, depending on the circumstances the user views the page under.

The sidebar is currently in the form:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        ....
    </ul>
</div>
```

where each < li > is a sidebar widget. Normally, sidebar widgets display one below the other in a vertical column, like so:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

What I'm trying to do is, using CSS, make alternating sidebar widgets go side-by-side in two columns, like so:

```
A B
C D
E F
```

So far, I was able to get them to line up appropriately with the following style...

```
#sidebar ul > li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    float: right;
}
```

...almost. The problem is, the widgets that end up in the 'B' and 'D' positions in the resulting sidebar are very short (one is a search box, the other a sign-up form), but they line up with their tops aligned vertically with the 'A' and 'C' widgets anyway. This causes large gaps.

Is there a way to close these gaps and give the illusion of a sidebar with two independent columns? Or is there a better way to do things than the method I've just described?

Comment: Can you provide some relevant HTML/CSS please?

Comment: You won't have to write a plugin - just css. If you could add the css media queries you're using, that would help provide a relevant answer.

Comment: As requested. Sidebar structure and media queries are in.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you float LI elements to the left, and then you clear the float on every nth child (every odd child in this case)?

Something like this:

```
#sidebar li {
    float: left;
}
#sidebar li:nth-child(odd) {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that with CSS selectors. I'll try it out and see if it works!

Comment: It almost works! There's just the issue of widgets of different heights leaving gaps on the other side (see above).